# Locale from CLPlacemark

Tags: ios, core-location, clplacemark

I try to get the <del>ISO Country Code</del> locale like "en_US" from a CLPlacemark Object. When i do a NSLog on the object, I get a lot of text including this:

```
address =                         {
                        "localized_address" =                             (
                                                            {
                                address =                                     {
                                    formattedAddressLine =                                         (
                                        "Piccadilly Circus",
                                        "Coventry Street",
                                        London,
                                        W1J,
                                        England
                                    );
                                    structuredAddress =                                         {
                                        administrativeArea = England;
                                        areaOfInterest =                                             (
                                            "Piccadilly Circus",
                                            "Great Britain"
                                        );
                                        country = "United Kingdom";
                                        countryCode = GB;
                                        dependentLocality =                                             (
                                            Mayfair
                                        );
                                        fullThoroughfare = "Coventry Street";
                                        geoId =                                             (
                                        );
                                        locality = London;
                                        postCode = W1J;
                                        subAdministrativeArea = London;
                                        subLocality = Mayfair;
                                        thoroughfare = "Coventry Street";
                                    };
                                };
                                locale = "en_US";
```

You can see in the last line exactly the information i need. But i've no clue how to access this information directly.

When I try to access the ISOcountryCode property of CLPlacemark i only get GB.

Thanks for your help
Bernhard

Comment: The `en_US` is not a country code, but a local. and is not depended on the place found but more the way the results are displayed.

Comment: No, you are talking about country code, which in your result is `GB` the `en_US` is the local is which the data is presented. In your case the data is present on `en_US` meaning that the counrty name is `Great Britain`, if the local `nl_NL` was use the country name would have been `Groot-Brittannië`. Meaning the local in your response is only representing the language formatting.

Comment: @rckoenes Oh thanks. Ok, i want to know the local (i will edit it in my question), which is present in the place mark description, but i cannot find how to access it.

Comment: There is no mention in the document on how to get or even set the local.

Comment: Yes that's right. But I'm wondering about the appearance of the local in the description of the CLPlacemark Object from NSLog.

Comment: Well the description method of `NSObject` return any kind of string without showing the internal structure. But you could try `[placemark valueForKeyPath:@"address.local"]`, but there are no grantees.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit hackish, but this is one way that you may be able to obtain the information

```
NSString *placemarkDescription = [yourPlacemark description];
NSString *regex = @"(locale)(\\s+)(=)(\\s+)("".*?"")(;)";
NSRange localeRange = [placemarkDescription rangeOfString:regex options:NSRegularExpressionSearch];
NSString *locale = [placemarkDescription substringWithRange:localeRange];
```

That regex is ugly and can probably be improved (I used http://txt2re.com), but this should be able to get the locale for you.

Comment: Ok, not exactly what i want but i works of course, at least at the moment.